# How to format dynamically created kotlin file in Intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am creating a plugin to generate some Kotlin files and xml files. After creating the Kotlin file I want to reformat the code programmatically. I found `com.google.googlejavaformat` for java code formatting.
Is there any libraries like com.google.googlejavaformat for Kotlin or how I can format the Kolin code?

Comment: reformat features of ktlint (which don't do what you need). In the IntelliJ formatter, the behavior you're talking about is controlled by the "Keep line breaks" option in the code style settings; you can try turning it off and see if you like the results better. And of course you're welcome to file YouTrack issues for formatter improvements.